# Convert html img element to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I have `html` page with content as

```
<div class="span12">
    <img id="myImg" src="myImage.png" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
</div>
```

where the actual size of `myImage.png` is `1600 * 900`. The image is rendered with size `796 * 448` (streched keeping the aspect ratio).

I am trying to convert the `img` element(with size 796 * 448) to a `canvas` element using `javascript` as

```
function convertImgToCanvas(){
    var myImgElement = document.getElementById("myImg");
    var myCanvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");
    myCanvasElement.width = myImgElement.width;
    myCanvasElement.height = myImgElement.height;
    var context = myCanvasElement.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(myImgElement,0,0);    
}
```

The resulting canvas has a size `1600 * 900`, not `796 * 448`. I am expecting the size of canvas to be `796 * 448`.

If I set the height and width of canvas as

```
myCanvasElement.width = '796px';
myCanvasElement.height = '448px';
```

the size of canvas become `796 * 448`, but image is cropped

Is there any solution to create a `canvas` from `img` element, with exactly same width and height as that of `img` element, without cropping the image ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using `drawImage` correctly. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

The third example allows you to specify x,y,width and height parameter of both source and destination: `ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);`

So the easiest fix in your case would be something like:

```
context.drawImage(myImgElement, 0, 0, 1600, 900, 0, 0, 796, 448);
```

And here it is in action (go Full Page because of the size):

```js
function convertImgToCanvas(){
    var myImgElement = document.getElementById("myImg");
    var myCanvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");
    // don't forget to add it to the DOM!!
    document.body.appendChild(myCanvasElement); 
    myCanvasElement.width = 796;
    myCanvasElement.height = 448;
    var context = myCanvasElement.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(myImgElement, 0, 0, 1600, 900, 0, 0, 796, 448);
    // remove the image for the snippet
    myImgElement.style.display = 'none';
}

convertImgToCanvas();
```

```html
<div class="span12">
    <img id="myImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" />
</div>
```

Comment: If 1600 and 900 are the image width/height, then just `context.drawImage(myImgElement, 0, 0, 796, 448);` will have the same exact effect. If 796 and 448 are relative dimensions, then `var rect = imageElement.getBoundingClientRect(); context.drawImage(myImgElement, 0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);` is what OP needs. And in any case, you should wrap the `convertImgToCanvas()` call into the img's onload event

Comment: I won't wrap it up into anything since I have no idea what OP wants to do with it. And yes, that's true about the drawImage, I wanted to show all the possibilities of that method.

Comment: Then I'm not sure it's the "easiest fix", since you show OP that `drawImage()` even has a cropping property. I think the "easiest" in his case is the one that does exactly what he wants, and only this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale).

```
function convertImgToCanvas(){
    var myImgElement = document.getElementById("myImg");
    var myCanvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");
    myCanvasElement.width = myImgElement.width;
    myCanvasElement.height = myImgElement.height;
    var context = myCanvasElement.getContext('2d');
    context.scale(myCanvasElement.width / myImgElement.width, myCanvasElement.height / myImgElement.height);
    context.drawImage(myImgElement, 0, 0);   
}
```

Comment: This is also what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Check link given below. You can convert image to HTML5 canvas element:
http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/img2canvas/

Comment: I am trying to convert an img element to canvas element using javascript, not an image.